# group list of objects by date and sort them time using rxjava

Tags: java, functional-programming, reactive-programming, rx-java

I have a list of restaurants' reservations.
I want to group them by day of the year and sort them by time on that day.
How can I do so using rxjava?

```
List reservations;

class Reservation {
   public String guestName;
   public long time; //time in milliseconds
}
```

OUTPUT

- day 5th of March 2015

  - reservation for 20:00
  - reservation for 22:00
- day 8th of of March 2015

  - reservation for 16:00

Answer (score 8):

To do this with RxJava, you could first sort your list by the time (`toSortedList`), then perform manual grouping in a `flatMap`, outputting an `Observable<List<Reservation>>` which gives you each day.

```
Observable.from(reservations)
    .toSortedList(new Func2<Reservation, Reservation, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Reservation reservation, Reservation reservation2) {
            return Long.compare(reservation.time, reservation2.time);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<List<Reservation>, Observable<List<Reservation>>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<List<Reservation>> call(List<Reservation> reservations) {
            List<List<Reservation>> allDays = new ArrayList<>();
            List<Reservation> singleDay = new ArrayList<>();
            Reservation lastReservation = null;
            for (Reservation reservation : reservations) {
                if (differentDays(reservation, lastReservation)) {
                    allDays.add(singleDay);
                    singleDay = new ArrayList<>();
                }
                singleDay.add(reservation);
                lastReservation = reservation;
            }
            return Observable.from(allDays);
        }
    })
    .subscribe(new Action1<List<Reservation>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(List<Reservation> oneDaysReservations) {
            // You will get each days reservations, in order, in here to do with as you please.
        }
    });
```

The `differentDays` method I leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Great example @Adam. I have a question though, can we use groupBy instead of flatMap.

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have the complete list of reservations (i.e. a `List<Reservation>`, not `Observable<Reservation>`), you don't really need RxJava here -- you can do what you need with Java 8 stream/collections API:

```
Map<Calendar, List<Reservation>> grouped = reservations
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(x.time);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return cal;
    }));
```

As you can see, all it does is `groupingBy` by day of year. If your initial data would use `Calendar` instead of `long` for the timestamp, this would've looked even simpler, something like:

```
Map<Calendar, List<Reservation>> grouped = reservations
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x.time.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)));
```